# Usage of .to_representation() in django-rest-framework resulting a slow response for a large(1000 records) list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an endpoint [www.exapmle.com/list?page_size=1000](http://www.exapmle.com/list?page_size=1000)

sample code looks like -

```
    class TestViewSetV10(ViewSet):
        queryset = Test.objects.all()#.order_by("pk")
        serializer_class = TestSerializerV10
        filterset_class = TestFilterV10
    
   class TestSerializerV10(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         #pass
```

Backend serializers is **serializers.ModelSerializer**, which is calling .to_representation() in the list. This is leading to a slow response, taking around 2 min.

Is there any way to optimize the above-mentioned case?

Comment: On the information given the only optimization suggestion would be to add pagination. Anything further you'll need to provide your full serializer and model fields.

Comment: Share your model and serializer.

Comment: There are simple fields in the model and serializers no m2m and other nesting... just need to get almost 1000 records in one request